# python program with multiple timers...threading ok?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

So I'm building an irrigation timer using python.

1. I want it to have the ability to control 10 different valves all with seperate timers
2. Do both timed irrigation(like for a garden). So this would be done by setting the days to irrigate and the time each day
3. Also want the ability to set a valve to cycle irrigation, this would be for misting propagating plants from cuttings(so this would be like 10 seconds on and 10 minutes off over and over again.

Here's the main question....There's a possibility of having as many as 10 timers running at once.  The way I am thinking there are two ways of doing the timers.  Either I can use threading OR I can have it check to see if the valve should be open each time it loops around and if TRUE it will set that valve pin HIGH. Then the next time it loops around if it's past the on time it will go LOW.

Will either way be fine?

I've read that when threading if two threads read from the same variable it can cause problems.  What about if two threads read from the same dictionary as long as it's a different index?  I've got it set up to where one dictionary saves the start time and end times for each valve.

Comment: Take a look at [ask] and [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 0):

> Will either way be fine?

Yes.

> I've read that when threading if two threads read from the same variable it can cause problems.

Actually no.  Python has a "Global Interpreter Lock" which prevents simultaneous access from multiple threads.  You don't need to worry about this at all.